# javascript how to make object inline

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have some objects with different nesting. Example:
**Object1**

```
{
    data: {somePage1.php:
                         {0: 
                             {function:'getPrice',
                             item:'0568000085',
                             line: 6},
                          1:
                             {function:'getCurrency',
                             item:'066000089'
                             line: 9}
                          },
           somePage2.php:...
      }
}
```

**Object2**

```
data: {EUR:{currency:45.0417}USD:{currency:33.0346}}
```

and so on. What I need is function, that will make any object inline

Wished result is:

**Object1**

```
{row1:{key1:somePage1.php, key2:0, function:'getPrice', item:'0568000085', line:6}
 row2:{key1:somePage1.php, key2:1, function:'getCurrency', item:'066000089', line:9}
 row3:{key1:somePage2.php, key2:0, function: ...                                   }
 row4:...
}
```

**Object2**

```
{
 row1:{key1:EUR, currency:45.0417}
 row2:{key1:USD, currency:33.0346}
}
```

It is clear that I need recursion, but I can't figure out the whole function, something like this:

```
    this.row = 0;
this.inline = function(d){
var that = this;
var data = d||that.data;//data have been append to this object onload
    $.each(data, function(attr, value){
        $.each(data[attr], function(att, val){
            if(typeof(val) === 'object' || typeof(val) === 'array'){
                that.inline(data[attr][att]);
            }else{
                $.each(data, function(){
                    that.row++;
                });
                console.log(value);
            }
        }); 
    });
console.log('======> '+that.row);
},
```

Comment: What kind of function do you want to do?

Comment: function that turn n-level nested object into 2-level, like a table

Comment: Why is 0 treated as key2 but function is not key3?

Comment: That is because 'function', 'item' and 'line' are at the last level of original object and I need to save them (see the top of this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function convert(d) {
  var r = {}, j = 0;
  for (var i in d) {
    r['row'+(j++)] = flatten({key1:i}, d[i], 2);
  }
  return r;
}
function flatten(r, d, l) {
  for (var i in d) {
    var c = d[i];
    if (c && typeof c == 'object') {
      r['key'+l] = i;
      flatten(r, c, l+1);
    } else {
      r[i] = c;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

This uses recursion and assumes the json is arbitrarily nested, and assigns key1, key2, etc to those keys whose value is a non-null object.

Edit: Fixed to make first key use rowX (sorry for all single letter var names)

Comment: key2, key3 and next keys in your solution contains an object. I need to get number of rows that is equal SUM of last level non-object values. I think I have to use double loop to check the deeper level for atomic values and if it is so go back for upper level and create rows.

Comment: Whoops I set wrong thing, should have set i into r['key'+l] instead of c. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works))))) Sorry that I can't vote up your answer, because I have not enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

This takes each (local) property of the object data, puts it as rowN property in rows and puts the old property name as the key property, I would not recommend incrementing the key property like in one of your examples.

```
var i = 0, rows = {}, data = {a: {t: 1}, b: {g: 2}, c: { z: 3}}; 
$.each(data, 
     function (prop, obj) { 
          rows['row' + i++] = $.extend({ key: prop}, obj); 
     }
);
```

BTW - double nested loops is not recursion.  It is also not clear that you need recursion, many solutions can be solved with both recursion and imperative execution with loops. The example above does not use recursion, but rather what is likely an imperative loop.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: task of this function is to linearize object with no matter nesting levels. Your solution is ok for 2-level nested object, but if data[obj] contains other objects this function only reduce nesting by 1 level, and that is main reason to use recursion.